# String equality with null handling

Tags: c#, .net, string, null, equality

I will often use this code to compare a string:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) && str1.Equals(str2)){
    //they are equal, do my thing
}
```

This handles the null case first etc.

Is there a cleaner way to do string comparison, perhaps with a single method call that will handle possible null values? I simply want to know that the strings are not equal if the testing value is null.

(I'm having dejavu that I may have asked this before, I apologize if so)

---

Update: In my case, the str2 is a known good string to compare to, so I don't need to check it for null. str1 is the "unknown" string which may be null, so I want to say "str1 does not equal str2" in the cases where str1 *is* null...

Comment: Your code is wrong; it will return true if `str1` is null and `str2` isn't.

Comment: @SLaks Actually, I think that is what he wants. At least based on the description

Comment: I have a ! in there, so it will only continue if the string to compare to is NOT null/empty. righto?

Comment: apparently c# 6 now has features for handling this

Answer (score 57):

Unlike Java, C# strings override the `==` operator:

```
if (str1 == str2)
```

If you want a case-insensitive comparison:

```
if (string.Equals(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: I will leave it to the OP, but I believe that the goal is to also fail if either side is `null`

Comment: @JustinPihony `str1 == str2 && str1 != null` is still a lot more elegant.

Comment: @p.s.w.g And, that is fine, but this answer does not say that. Also, see my answer for a way to encapsulate this...as stated, the naming of the method might be hardest

Answer (score 22):

If you do *not* want to treat two `null` strings as equal to each other, your code is optimal.

If, on the other hand, you want to treat `null` values as equal to each other, you can use

```
object.Equals(str1, str2)
```

for a more "symmetric" approach that also handles `null` values.

This is not the only approach to a symmetric check of string equality that treats `null` strings as equal: you could also use `string.Equals(str1, str2)` or even `str1 == str2`, which redirects to `string.Equals`.

Comment: ok, this will actually work for me as str2 is a known value and not null. Thus null comparison won't matter.

Comment: This is useful functionality to know. However, it doesn't help in my particular case, as an empty value in the first object is null, while an empty value in the second value is an empty string. But thanks!

Comment: @CigarDoug With C# strings there is no such thing as "an empty value" that is "null". Unfortunately, they often do look the same, causing a lot of confusion. You can fix this by using `object.Equals(str1 ?? "", str2 ?? "")` expression.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In my particular case, I am comparing the current value of a SharePoint control (null if empty) to the current value of the field in the SharePoint list (empty string if empty, based on the method I use to get the value). So in this one case, I need to check for null and then check for equality. But I will look at your example to see if it accomplishes the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Try this code:
    `string s1 = null;
    string s2 = null;
 
    if (s1 == s2) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Equal.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NOT equal.");
    }`

It will print "Equal." (beware: this is only true for strings).

Comment: @Grimm The fact that the code in your comment is correct has nothing to do with my answer also being verifiably correct. Your code is equivalent to `string.Equals(str1, str2)` to which `operator==` redirects.

Comment: I had the impression that you wanted to express with your answer that *only* object.Equals(str1, str2) considers null values as equal, but not "==".

Comment: @Grimm That's fair, I added a note to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Excellent. I reread the opening question and sure enough, he doesn't ask for "==" at all. However, comparing with == or != is so common under C# (as opposed to the constant use of .Equals() under Java) that I missed it while reading the answer. So in terms of content I was really wrong and you are right - but this way it won't happen to the next reader as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is some years old and I think the solution from dasblinkenlight is functionally perfect for what you asked for.
However I do prefer this code for readability reasons:

```
String.Equals(str1, str2)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no built in way to do this, but you could create an extension method to encapsulate this.

```
public static StringExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsNotNullAndEquals(this string str1, string str2)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) && str1.Equals(str2)
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
str1.IsNotNullAndEquals(str2);
```

Naming is going to be your hardest thing here IMO...since you need to convey that you are only null checking `str1`. When used as an extension method, it reads fairly well, but if used as a regular static, then it doesn't convey that as well.

Comment: This is what I figured would be needed. Was really more curious if there is something built-in that would handle this, but is looking like a "no". Thanks!

Comment: actually, would an extension method work for str1 if str1 is a null? I'm thinking it will bomb with a null exception

Comment: @boomhauer First, I believe so, but will verify shortly. Second, if this works, an upvote and accept are appreciated

Comment: @boomhauer I did not test it, but had more time to remember this. This will work even if `str1` is null. The reason is because this is just syntactic sugar for calling `StringExtensions.IsNotNullAndEquals(str1, str2)` It only LOOKS like it is a method call on `str1`

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1) ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str2) : str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
object.Equals(str1, str2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In more recent C# versions, we also have the null coalescing option now. This isn't an exact solution but can be a cleaner one for some purposes. It takes some liberties with "upgrading" str1 to an empty string for comparison purposes, in the instances where it actually is a null.

```
if((str1??"").Equals(str2))
{
    //they are equal, do things here
}
```

Comment: nearly - I suspect a typo..  needs '??' (coalescing ) vs '?'.  So answer could be if ( ( str1??"" ).Equals( str2 ) ). { they are equal }.

Comment: yep you were right.  I mixed it with the other new operator for calling methods on potentially null objects

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answer while ago and there's good answers, although as per Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0) you can use the following to check both cases:

```
if(string.Equals(str1,str2)){
    //they are equal with null handling
}
```

Comment: good answer but was actually already proposed